# Schedule to turn off monitor via crontab?

Tags: shutdown, monitor, cron

I want to turn off monitor on a specific period of time automatically (for example between 07:00 and 11:00). Is there any command to be set in crontab file? Is there any better way?

---

In summary:

Turning off the monitor at 07:00 automatically.

Turning on the monitor at 11:00 automatically.

- scren-saver & lock screen are disabled!

Comment: Close-voter(s): The answer here is generally applicable to other people who want something similar--even if the OP never replied back this should still not be closed as not reproducible. (Also, the OP said it would take about *one day* to come back and check if the answer worked.) If there's some other reason to close this, I recommend commenting.

Comment: Related [Manually turn off monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253818/manually-turn-off-monitor/253821#253821)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are using the default [gnome-screensaver](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver) for Ubuntu, open a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) and run next commands followed by instructions:

1. `mkdir -p bin` - this command will make a `bin` directory in your `home` folder if you don't already have it.
2. `gedit ~/bin/screen_on_or_off.sh` - this will create the new file `screen_on_or_off.sh` in gedit.
3. Copy and paste the next script:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   export DISPLAY=:0 #very important if you want to be runned by a cron job

   current_hour=$(date +"%k")

   # Defining the disable_screensaver function
   function disable_screensaver {
       # Disabling sleep time
       # 0 value will never turn the screen off; you can change this value as you wish:
       # for example to turn the screen of after 10 min, use 600
       gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac 0
       gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-battery 0
       gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
   }

   # Defining the enable_screensaver function
   function enable_screensaver {
       # Enabling sleep time to 1 second
       gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac 1
       gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-battery 1
       gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 1

       notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "Let's go to sleep now!"
   }

   if [ "$current_hour" -ge "7" ] && [ "$current_hour" -lt "11" ]; then
       enable_screensaver
   else
       disable_screensaver
   fi

   exit 0
   ```
4. Save the file and close it.
5. Go back into terminal and run: `chmod +x screen_on_or_off.sh` - to grant execute access for the script.
6. Just for test, to run your new script, type in terminal `~/bin/screen_on_or_off.sh`.
7. Edit the crontab entries using `crontab -e` command (by default this will edit the current logged-in users crontab) and add the following line:

   ```bsh
   */1 * * * * /home/$USER/bin/screen_on_or_off.sh  #change $USER with your username
   ```

   I have set the cron job for every minute, but you can change as you wish or as you think is better. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron in this sense.
8. Save the file and check the new crontab entry with `crontab -l`.

Now your screen will turn off every day between 7 and 11.

Comment: I've disabled gnome-screensaver and lock-screen, this is the reason that I want to turn off the monitor by command line automatically! Another note: The computer is at work, I'm on vacation now; however, I'll check your instruction tomorrow and put a feedback here :)

Answer (score 3):

Newer and much simpler answer, put this in cron:

```
0 07 * * *  export DISPLAY=:0 && xset dpms force off
0 11 * * *  export DISPLAY=:0 && xset dpms force on
```