# Brightness settings from terminal

Tags: command-line, display, brightness

I do change the `Turn screen off when incative for:` often using the below screen in Ubuntu 12.04. How do I change the same from the terminal? I did check in the gconf-editor, but couldn't figure it out.

[image]

I use the below commands for turning the monitor off and for the locking the screen quickly from the terminal.

```
alias off='xset dpms force off'  
alias lock='gnome-screensaver-command -a'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the time of inactivity after which to turn the screen off from terminal using next commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac <nr_of_sec>
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-battery <nr_of_sec>
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay <nr_of_sec>
```

Change `<nr_of_sec>` as you wish. For example, for 3 minutes, use 3x60=180:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac 180
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-battery 180
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 180
```

If you will use 0, the screen will never turn off.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/313155/147044.

To change the brightness through terminal, use this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/56171/147044. I tested this method on 13.04 and is working.

Comment: How about the brightness controls?

Comment: @Seth See http://askubuntu.com/a/56171/147044

Comment: Is there any list of all the different properties for gesettings. I will try it out and upvote.

Comment: @PraveenSripati See `man gsettings`.

Comment: Only `idle-delay` is needed on a desktop machine. Tested on 14.04.1

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following.

```
xrandr --output <output name> --brightness "<X>"
```

Where `<X>` is a number between 1 (being full brightness) and 0 (with the backlight off) and `<output name>` can be obtained with `xrandr --listmonitors` ("LVDS1" or "LVDS-1" may work).
:)