# Gnome source code of fade out effect for inactivity

Tags: gnome, 13.04, source-code

Where I can find the source code for fade out animation when the computer is inactive for x minutes?

I guess that it somewhere in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui` but I want to find the line.

[image]

Note - this question is NOT a duplicate of this:

- [Brightness settings from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313455/brightness-settings-from-terminal)

  I want to modify the Gnome code. I want to localize where the fadeOut effect is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're looking in the right way. The respective effect of fade out is realised by `gnome-screensaver`. Now, you can check (with `which gnome-screensaver` in terminal) that you have installed on your system `gnome-screensaver`, but the problem is that this is the compiled version, so no sources on your system in this sense.

But, don't worry, you can download `gnome-screensaver` source package from Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/gnome-screensaver. The source code of fade out effect can be found in `gs-fade.c` and `gs-fade.h` files from `src` directory:

[image: gs-fade.c]

Comment: Please add how to download sources, compile them and install them on my system. Thanks!

Comment: @Johnツ Well, this is the direct link for download: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/gnome-screensaver/3.6.1-0ubuntu3/+files/gnome-screensaver_3.6.1.orig.tar.xz (you can find it in the link that I gave you in the answer). To install, follow this post: [Installing applications from source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/123077/installing-applications-from-source)