# Custom Shortcut for switching off the display

Tags: keyboard, monitor, shortcuts

I want to add a Custom Shortcut (Keyboard → Custom Shortcuts → Add) for turning off the display but to do that, what *'Command'* should I should use?

I want to set a button to switch off the display and switch on.

Comment: I have tried this my self and placed here. 100% working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ xset dpms force off
```

Screen wakes up after moving the mouse or pressing a key.

[Manually turn off monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253818/manually-turn-off-monitor)

Comment: Thats working, Thank U!  I used command as 'xset dpms force off'!

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install python-xlib
```

after installing it ,type as

```
gedit monitoroff.sh
```

and paste the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import subprocess
from Xlib import X
from Xlib.display import Display

display = Display(':0')
root = display.screen().root
root.grab_pointer(True,
        X.ButtonPressMask | X.ButtonReleaseMask | X.PointerMotionMask,
        X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, 0, 0, X.CurrentTime)
root.grab_keyboard(True,
        X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, X.CurrentTime)

subprocess.call('xset dpms force off'.split())
p = subprocess.Popen('gnome-screensaver-command -i'.split())
time.sleep(1)

while True:
    print display.next_event()
    p.terminate()
    break
```

Then type as

```
chmod +x monitoroff.sh
```

Then open your unity dash and type as keyboard and open it.

after opening it click at + symbol to add it.

Then in the name field type name as `monitor off` & at command field type path of the script. In my case it is `~/monitoroff.sh`

after adding it click ok.

then select it with mouse and then press your hotkey , in my case it is F11.

to power on your mouse again click your mouse or press escape key .

Then [image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah let me know if any...