# How can I make a keyboard shortcut to have the screen turn *and stay* off?

Tags: 14.04

I want to use a keyboard short cut to manually turn the screen off.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/558408/2413) answer reduces the brightness but doesn't turn the screen off.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/253821/2413) answer does what I want if launched from the terminal, but when used as a keyboard short-cut, the screen off only lasts 1 second (and the screen comes on after one second). The same problem occurs with `xset dpms force standby`.

For some reason, I can't get [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/369036/2413)  answer to work (it just doesn't do anything).

(the computer is a laptop and I want the monitor to come back alive if either the mouse is moved or any key pressed, as in [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/253821/2413) answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the screen comes back on is because you've just fired a keyboard event. It works on my computer but that could be explained by event timing, bus types, who knows.

Anyway, try giving it a bit of lead time for any X events to seep away:

```
sleep 1 && xset dpms force standby
```

Comment: When I put this in the command field (of the create shortcut) menu, press my keyboardshortcut and wait (more than 1 sec), nothing happens~ I know it's dicey but would you have any idea?

Comment: In some circumstances, you may need to wrap it in something that makes it a single command, ie: `sh -c "sleep 1 && xset dpms force standby"`

Comment: Perfect, that second one works magic!