# Keyboard shortcut to lock screen & turn off monitor

Tags: shortcut-keys, cinnamon

I can [turn off the monitor](https://askubuntu.com/a/253821/128334) and [lock the screen](https://askubuntu.com/a/7780/128334) manually with `cinnamon-screensaver-command -l && xset dpms force off`.

However, if I try to put that command as a custom shortcut in Keyboard->shortcuts, the monitor doesn't turn off, and if I switch the order then nothing happens.

How can I get a shortcut to fire both commands?

Comment: Try it in terminal first, it is easier to check whether it works then. you may also want to try: `cinnamon-screensaver-command -l & xset dpms force off` and `gnome-screensaver-command -l && xset dpms force off`.

Comment: @wilf Thank you for looking wilf!  It does work in terminal as expected.  It doesn't as a keyboard shortcut.  Would it make a difference if it were in a bash script?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: The default shortcut is `Ctrl+Alt+L`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It might work if you did it like this in the keyboard shortcut settings::

```
bash -c "cinnamon-screensaver-command -l; xset dpms force off;"
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :-)