# Differences how to run scripts at startup

Tags: bash, scripts, startup

I've read various questions about `how to run script at startup` but I'm not quite sure what the differences are and what's the actually the right way to do it without GUI.

- `/etc/rc.local`
- cron job using `@reboot`
- `~/.profile`
- `/.bash_profile`
- `/.bash_login`

---

**Examples I need to run at startup**

- `apt-get update`
- set some permissions
- set display brightness
- turn numlock on
- setup touchpad
- run some apps
- run some scripts as root (should I call them with `sudo` even if main script is already executed as a root?)
- run some scripts without root

---

It would be nice to has a single one script that handles all these things in the one file. How to do it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~/.profile`, `/.bash_profile`, and `/.bash_login` are better for defining the environment variables and setting up the environment, than for running scripts. I would not recommend these.

`/etc/rc.local` can be used for that, but remember that it will start before GUI starts . Unless it is for a script that only sends notification to GUI. Note that you will need to call your script from `/etc/rc.local`  in format `/full/path/to/script &` (`&` to avoid blocking other scripts you may have there from execution). You will also need `export DISPLAY=:0` variable in either the script itself or within `/etc/rc.local` . Apps that need GUI will need this variable to exist. Same idea with `cron job using @reboot`.

If you want to run scripts at GUI login, the proper way is to create `.desktop` file for each script in your `~/.config/autostart/` folder. You can do it by hand, or use Startup Applications app that does exactly the same thing for you. Just open the Unity  Dash and type in "Startup Applications"

#### Overview of your examples

- `apt-get update` doesn't need GUI , just network. `/etc/rc.local` is ok for this one.
- `set some permissions` , this doesn't need GUI too, just use `/etc/rc.local`
- `set display brightness`  doesn't need GUI too , but may need root privillege. If you want to change it before login , you will need to write to a special file. Consult [my other post](https://askubuntu.com/a/730067/295286) on this subject
- `turn numlock on` may not need GUI,too
- `setup touchpad` depending on your method, may or may not need GUI
- `run some apps` if they are GUI apps, they will need to be started from Startup Applications I described above.
- `run some scripts as root`  you can use `/etc/rc.local` or `cron` for these.  Running GUI apps as root is bad idea for many reasons, so please avoid that.
- `run some scripts without root` use the Startup Applications method.

Comment: Awesome response! Startup Applications (GUI settings) works but it's not portable, e.g. when I need to copy all settings to another computer. That's why I need it done without GUI.

Comment: By another computer ,  you mean another computer with Ubuntu or some other distro ? It is portable - you just need to copy your scripts and those files in `~/.config/autostart`

Comment: I guess you're right. You're my hero, @Serg. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure to help :)