# Screen flickering on boot after upgrade to 18.04 and slow boot

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 yesterday, and my first boot was fine. I have a double partition Windows 10  - Ubuntu. After I restarted my PC I selected Ubuntu from GRUB, the loading screen appears, after more or less 3 seconds it started flickering with a period of around 2 seconds (1 sec black, 1 sec Ubuntu [loading screen](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ubuntu-boot-flash-screen.jpg)). I waited about 10 minutes then restarted but the problem reappears.

So I restarted and ran in recovery mode. 
After doing a `fsck` the system boots properly (with 800x600 resolution). If I restart it boots properly (in correct resolution) once. But if I shut down I need to `fsck` and restart each time.

I searched around and found that it may be a graphics driver related issue. I tried to update my drivers but under **Additional Drivers** in **Software and Updates** I can't find any available additional driver. Then I tried to update GRUB but still no results. I can't wipe out the disk; it would take hours to back up all important data.

Additional info:

```
$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password di lollouno: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Carrizo
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: ca
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:40 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Update:

Today I was able to boot. It took about 10 minutes, so finally I am not sure if yesterday it really was impossible to boot or if I did not wait enough.

Anyway help would be appreciated to speed up boot

Comment: Check the solutions listed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029517/amd-rx480-screen-flicker-after-update-to-18-04

Comment: The second part of the solution worked for me, or at least for now... TY

Comment: I'm not familiar with AMD, but i solved this for nVidia by adding an nvidia ppa. Look for an AMD PPA in launchpad.
Also, use `dmesg` to debug slow boot, show the boot `dmesg`

Comment: Same problem here, CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz, with Intel HD 530 integrated graphics (only).
After 3 minutes screen on/screen off blinking, turned off the PC, restartet PC, next time boot was finished in 10 seconds. Don't know why! Spooky!