# Flickering row of pixels top of monitor after 18.04 upgrade

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, 18.04, monitor

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, and I have a line (or two) of pixels at the top of my screen that's distract. It goes along the width of the screen. I have 2 monitors, both which work fine beside this. This only happens on screen #1. It flickers mostly randomly.

Here's a video:

[image]
Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORFxA.jpg

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you have an AMD graphics card check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029517/amd-rx480-screen-flicker-after-update-to-18-04

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that didn't fix it