# how to turn off monitor advance

Tags: shortcut-keys, monitor

So i looked through the posts here and i found this helpful advice: [Manually turn off monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253818/manually-turn-off-monitor)

I assigned a hotkey to turn my monitor off with the following code:

```
sleep 0.3 && xset dpms force off
```

However i was wondering if there is an easy way to keep the monitor off until the exact same shortcut is pressed.
I usually turn off the monitor to save up some battery life and every little movement turns it back on (accidental key press, mouse move, or a touch pad contact).

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04, dpms not working properly with GNOME Wayland

```
$ xset -q

DPMS (Energy Star):
Display is not capable of DPMS
```

You can try the command below,
to turn off monitor:

```
busctl --user set-property org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig PowerSaveMode i 1
```

To turn on monitor:

```
busctl --user set-property org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig PowerSaveMode i 0
```

It works for me.

[(Link)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253818/manually-turn-off-monitor/1062631#1062631)