# unable to power off macbook display w/ ubuntu server

Tags: server, power-management, macbook

I have two macbooks, one running 16.04 server, another running 18.04 server. I'm trying to disable the monitors to save power

It seems `setterm` is the command I should be using based on [this power management doc](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Battery-Powered/methods.html) and [this post](https://superuser.com/a/31885/144997)

> If instead you're using the Linux console (not X-Windows), you'll want
>   to use setterm(1):

I've tried a couple of the commands to no avail

- `setterm --powersave on`
- `setterm --half-bright on`
- `setterm --powersave powerdown`

Essentially nothing happens when I run these commands. I'm running them at a console on the laptop itself (not over SSH).

`setterm --cursor off|on` do work, so I feel like `setterm` is the right direction, but for some reason the power management options do nothing. Maybe there's something I could install that would fix that?

I was looking into disabling kernel modules as well, I've got the nouveau driver, when I run `sudo rmmod -f nouveau` I get

```
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:793 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'nouveau': Resource temporarily unavailable
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module nouveau: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I also tried changing the keyboard layout to a Macbook layout and using the built-in keys, but when I press the function key and the appropriate function key to change the brightness, it just acts as if I'm typing random characters into the terminal.

How can I power off my displays?

Answer (score 0):

Try `setterm -blank force`.
You can also try using `xrandr` to set the brightness to 0. Use `xrandr` to get your display name and do `xrandr --output <display name here> --brightness 0`.

Related questions I found: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366868/macbook-ubuntu-server-how-can-i-have-the-screen-turn-off-when-lid-closed-but-k
[Manually turn off monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253818/manually-turn-off-monitor)

Edit: If that doesn’t work, try using DPMS to turn off your monitor. You can use `xset`. Or, you can also use `vbetool` although they seem to be the same.

`sleep 3; xset dpms force off` (note: the sleep is needed so that it doesn’t turn back on which is a known bug with `xset dpms force off`)

`vbetool dpms off`

Comment: I've tried `setterm -blank force`, but it doesn't power off the display, it just blanks it out. I also tried `xrandr`, that is for X, which I'm not using.